# How to set a data binding in element which is created by JS?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, polymer, polymer-1.0

I try to add a data binding to an element, which is created in JS, but it does not work. Either there is a string with the code or the value stay empty.

`el.setAttribute('value', '{{value}}');` The content in the Input was is'{{value}}'

`el.setAttribute('value', value);` The content in the Input was is empty, because `value` is empty.

How is it possible to create a element dynamically and use data binding?

Answer (score 0):

Creating element dynamically is another subject but here I tried to bind a value dynamically to an existing element dynamically, you may use like :

```
<sample-elem  data = "{{data}}"></sample-elem> 
...
<script>
    class MyApp Polymer.Element { 

        static get is() { return "jobijoy-app"; } 
        static get properties() { return {
           data: {
               type:String,
               value(): {return "";}
            }

         bindValue() {
             this.set('data','Some data here');
         }

 customElements.define(MyApp.is, MyApp);
 </script>
```

At this point you have a `data` property in `sample-elem` with data value is 'Some data here'

I am not sure but here with this code, you may create dynamically `sample-elem`

```
ready(){
super.ready();
    var dynamicEl = document.createElement("sample-elem");
    document.body.appendChild(dynamicEl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dynamicEl = document.createElement("sample-elem");
```

If you create an element using `createElement` you can use either one of these before you append it.

```
dynamicEl.value = this.value;                // First way
dynamicEl.setAttribute('value', this.value;  // Second way
```

`this.value` calls the property value set in the element where you try to create your other element programmatically.